# How to get the value of a field that has been bound to a FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have `<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server">`.

In my codebehind Page_Load I bind an SQL DataSource to FormView1.

I need to access the value of one of the fields in the DataSource in Page_Load just after `FormView1.DataBind();`.

During debug in the locals window I can see all the fields in the DataItem property of FormView1.

However I cannot figure out the code to access the value of any of those fields.

NOTE: This field is not used in the form. I need its value to set visibility on/off of an asp:label.

```
FormView1.DataSource = from prop in dataContext.Properties
   join sub in dataContext.SuburbsWithProperties on prop.SuburbID equals sub.SuburbID
   where prop.PropertyID == propNo
   select new
   {
       prop.PropertyID,
       prop.SuburbID,
       prop.Rent,
   etc
}
```

**** So with the help of ConnorsFan I have been able to get my field value.

```
var dataItem = formView1.DataItem as object;
var dataItemFields = dataItem.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(dataItem, null));
    var fieldValue = (string)dataItemFields["MyFieldName"];
```

Answer (score -1):

(The suggestion below is not valid after the update of the question, which shows that the data source is a LINQ query)

<s>You can cast the `DataItem` to its actual type, which is a DataRowView. You can then access the value of each field:</s>

`DataRowView drv = FormView1.DataItem as DataRowView;
int ID = (int)drv["ClientID"];
string name = (string)drv["ClientName"];`

---

On the other hand, if the Label belongs to the FormView, you can set the visibility condition in the markup with a data-binding expression:

If the field contains a boolean value:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("fieldName") %>' ... />
```

If the field contains a string:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("fieldName") == "Some value" %>' ... />
```

Comment: Unfortunately `DataRowView drv = FormView1.DataItem as DataRowView;` returns null. In debug `FormView1.DataItem ` is defintiely there.

Comment: Thanks ConnorsFan, I'll go with your other suggestions of `<asp:Label runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("fieldName") %>' ... />` etc as I've been banging my head for too long on this. But I'd still love to get my question working.

Comment: If you see FormView1.DataItem in the Locals, its data type should be displayed. What is it? Not DataRowView? You could insert an image of the Locals window in your question.

Comment: It's Anonymous containing {data1 = "test1", data2 = "sam", data3 = "bob"}. So now it needs to be turned into a collection I suppose. Another post suggested this `var dict = a.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(a, null));` which I will try later but I have to go now. (I will report back).

Comment: I would have to see how you define your data source. Can you add the relevant code in your question? I thought that you were using a standard SQL query. When I use that, each DataItem is a DataRowView.

Comment: DataSource now in original question.